# AudioGraph in Unity3D TypeLoadException could not find method due to type load error

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, dll

I'm trying to develop an application using Unity3D which has to access microphone and send the captured audio on a socket.
I want to run this application on Hololens.

I've seen that the Microphone class of Unity has not an automatic way to detect the end of a sentence, so I was thinking to use the AudioGraph class from the Windows.Media.Audio namespace which I've already used in a n UWP project; this because the AudioGraph class automatically detect the end of a sentence and create an audio segment which I can write on my socket.

I've created a class library which expose some function and I want to use this as a managed plugin in Unity.
The problem which I'm facing is that the class library is builded and imported in the Unity editor succesfully, but when I run the Unity project this will fail with:

> TypeLoadException: could not find method due to a type load error

OR

> TypeLoadException: Failure has occurred while loading a type load

I've discovered that this error is caused by this declaration I have inside my managed plugin:

```
AudioGraph graph;
```

removing every reference and call to AudioGraph instance or methods the managed plugin will work without errors, the plugin fails only if there are call to classes which belongs to Windows.Media.Audio.

As a test I've added this method in the plugin:

```
public int c;

public void AddValues(int a, int b)
{
        c = a + b;
}
```

and doing this call from the Unity script I don't get errors:

```
UWPUtilities utils = new UWPUtilities();
Debug.Log("Generated random: " + utils.GenerateRandom(1, 99));
```

with instances of AudioGraph in the dll project the unity debugger doesn't even reack instantiation of UWPUtilities, it throws the `TypeLoadException`.

How could I use the AudioGraph class, or every class in the Windows.Media.Audio namespace?
Is this approach possible o I must use the microphone class from Unity and implement myself the silence detection feature?

Answer (score 0):

AudioGraph is a UWP API.  Is your Unity project targeting UWP?  I get the impression that it is not.

I do not think it is possible to use AudioGraph directly from within Unity C# script in a Unity desktop app; I think the Mono runtime used in that configuration does not have the ability to connect to the AudioGraph services.  Since this is also the runtime used in the Unity Player, I think you would also not be able to use AudioGraph while playing your scene(s) inside Unity itself.

However, if it is an option for your app to target UWP, your odds improve.  I actually successfully created a UWP-targeting Unity project that used AudioGraph for sound.  I had to:

- Create an interface with the sound operations my Unity app needed, and add this interface to the Unity project, along with a static field holding "the current sound interface"
- Create a mock implementation of that interface that is used by default, when playing the app inside Unity (this lets me use Unity for testing everything but the sound)
- Create a separate UWP .NET C# DLL project that implements the interface, using AudioGraph; add the project to the UWP solution generated by Unity
- Modify the main UWP app code to update the static "the current sound interface" field, such that when running under UWP, the interface routes sound operations to AudioGraph via the DLL

This actually worked.  I am currently revising it however, as I decided I didn't want my core audio processing to be in C#.  I also want a solution that works for both desktop and UWP, which this solution does not.  I am currently trying to decide whether to write a P/Invoke C++ wrapper around AudioGraph, or to write a P/Invoke C++ library based on WASAPI.  Either way I will update this answer with a link once I have something, moderators permitting.

Comment: The error is caused only if the project is run from the editor.
If I try to build it for UWP it will show an error saying that Task doesn't exist in the current context, but I have the System.Threading.Task included and the VS project will compile without errors.
I think I have to resolve this problem, not the first one.

Comment: Curiously Task will work only in the editor but will not build if the target is UWP